# Is there any way changing Tableau datasource's link with recreating dashboard?

Tags: tableau-api

Hi our company requires us to change databases to other server, so we need rebuild Tableau dashboard using new datasource (same table but on different platform).
Is there any way I can just only edit and update the datasource link in Tableau, don't need to rebuild the dashboard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace data source. Connect to the new data source. The go Data > Replace Data Source. See the docs for more details. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/connect_basic_replace.html

Comment: Also if you keeping the same type of database, say switching from one Postgres server to another, or from excel file to another, it is even easier. simply edit the connection info on the data source connection panel.